# Join multiple tables in SQL - [Troubleshoot]

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I want to join three (or more) tables to make my life easier in Access.

however, when I add the code:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Inventory i
LEFT JOIN tbl_FlameConditions1 fc1
ON i.ID = fc1.SampleID
LEFT JOIN tbl_SolventComponents1 sc1
ON i.ID = sc1.SampleID;
```

to my query in Access, it gives me an error message:

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'i.ID = fc1.SampleID
    LEFT JOIN tbl_SolventComponents1 sc1
    ON i.ID = sc1.SampleI' ".

And I forgot about the D and ; in the statement intentionally, since this is what Access gives me...

Does anyone know how to fix this? I already tried various different combinations. Also, if I only try to join 2 tables (either one), it works fine with the code I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add parenthesis in Access:

```
SELECT * FROM (tbl_Inventory i
LEFT JOIN tbl_FlameConditions1 fc1
ON i.ID = fc1.SampleID)
LEFT JOIN tbl_SolventComponents1 sc1
ON i.ID = sc1.SampleID;
```